How I can create as much buttons as I want in Telebot?
Im trying to make bot send messages and buttons for each message. But bot can create from 2 to 4 buttons when when more buttons required. After third button, it gives me error Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID.

import telebot
from telebot import types
import wikipedia
 wikipedia.set_lang(lang)
           searchCover = wikipedia.search(message.text)
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Думаю, вы искали... ")
           print(searchCover)
           print(searchCover)
           print(searchCover)
           for i in range(0, len(searchCover)):
                time.sleep(3)
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
              
                gotoThis = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Искать это", callback_data=searchCover[i])
                markup.add(gotoThis)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, searchCover[i], reply_markup=markup)




I tried to add breaks and sort results that only can be useful
